# Why are these React components overlapping?

Tags: react-native

I rendered two similar components. Each component has an icon and text, and each of them should not be overlapping. What's wrong with my styling?

```
    import Icon from "react-native-elements/src/icons/Icon";

<TouchableOpacity onPress={_ => playSound(audio)} style={{
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexGrow:1,
  flex: 1
}}>
  <View>
    <Icon name="volume-up" color={PRIMARY_BG} size={24}/>
  </View>
  <View>
    <Text style={{
      flexGrow: 1,
      fontSize: 8, 
      backgroundColor: GRAY
   }}>
     [{locale}]{this.props.pronunciation[locale][0]}
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here's the output:

[image: inline]

## Parent container style

```
headItemContent: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
```

Comment: I think it's about parent style of these two `<Touchables />`. I made a mini project they looks fine.

Comment: I updated the parent style. it should be fine also

Comment: Were is the image meant to be? Under the text?

Comment: the image is a icon from react-native-elements

Comment: I think whats confusing me is i do not know what you are expecting it to look like. Could you add a sample image of what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your images are meant to be, but the problem is the flexDirection you have set. The flexDirection on the touchableOpacity should be column:

```
flexDirection: "column"
```

Since yours is row, the images and text are rendering beside each other. There is not enough space so they are over lapping. So change the flexDirection and that should fix it.

**Edit - Or add flex to your image and text:**

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Icon name="volume-up" color={PRIMARY_BG} size={24}/>
</View>
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Text style={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    fontSize: 8, 
    backgroundColor: GRAY
  }}>
   [{locale}]{this.props.pronunciation[locale][0]}
  </Text>
</View>
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Of course not, i want them align side by side in a row :)

Comment: @newBike Maybe add "flex: 1" to your image and your text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464294/mapped-items-overlap-with-each-other Could you take a look at this?